# C#: Change element in list tree, without for loops

Tags: c#

i have this:

```
private static List<Mod> m_modList;

public static void UpdateScript(Script rScript)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m_modList.Count; i++)
        for (int b = 0; b < m_modList[i].scriptModule.Count; b++)
            for (int m = 0; m < m_modList[i].scriptModule[b].scripts.Count; m++)
                if (m_modList[i].scriptModule[b].scripts[m].name == rScript.name)
                    m_modList[i].scriptModule[b].scripts[m] = rScript;
}
```

can I somehow reduce the amount of code, and not use so many for loops?

Comment: What's `Mod`? Please provide a [mre]. Why don't you want for loops?

Comment: You could use `for each` instead of `for` which would make the code more readable and less prone to typos - https://dotnetfiddle.net/VwaXIK

Comment: I would create some helper methods in the sub classes and Mod class.

Comment: You can hide the loops, so they are run by framework code instead of your own code, but not eliminate them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you could simplify your code for better understanding (even for yourself) :

```
foreach(Mod mod in m_modList)
{
  foreach(ScriptMod scriptMod in mod.scriptModule)
  {
    for(int i = 0;i<scriptMod.scripts.Count();i++)
    {
      if(scriptModule.scripts[i].name==rScript.name)
      scriptModule.scripts[i]=rScript;
    }
  }
}
```

You eventually could simplify it like that :

```
foreach(ScriptModule scriptMod in m_modList.SelectMany(x=>x.scriptModule))
{
  for(int i = 0;i<scriptModule.scripts.Count();i++)
  {
    if(scriptModule.scripts[i].name==rScript.name)
    scriptModule.scripts[i]=rScript;
  }
}
```

in the case `scriptModule.scripts[i]=rScript;` could be replaced by a Clone, you can use several `SelectMany` :

```
foreach(Script script in m_modList.SelectMany(x=>x.scriptModule.SelectMany(y=>y.scripts)))
{
  if(script.Name==rScript.Name)
  {
    script.Clone(rScript);
  }
}
```

(cannot assign an object in foreach).